# Plotting the string value frequency in python

Tags: python-3.x, plot, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, kaggle

So I have this data frame related to species of spiders and I wanted to see what are the top 10 highest occurring family of spiders. So I used the below code to find it out:

```
n=10
dfc['family'].value_counts()[:n].index.tolist()
```

I want to create a plot which will show how many of each of those top 10 species exists in the data frame. That is, I want a plot that says 300 of the first species exist and 200 of the second species exist in the data frame, just like this. But I cannot quite figure out the code for this.

Can anyone help me out with it?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your dataframe looks like at all, it is a little tough to give a precise answer, and I didn't check the below code on a dataframe because I didn't have something handy. (also, I assume you are using `pandas` here).

It sounds like you want (or at least could use) a dataframe that has a column of families and then the next column is just the count of that family in the original. You can accomplish this with `groupby()`.

```py
df2 = dfc.groupby(['family']).count()
```

If you want to then just have the top 10 left on there to make it easy to plot, you can use the `nlargest()` function in pandas.

```py
df2 = df2.nlargest(10,'family')
```